# Death to humans by deadly monsters

Tags: apocalypse, creature-design

Those pesky humans. We, Evil Overlords have a tough job with them. They can be set to slaves, but only for relatively short period of time. They promise you loyalty ... and snap! There is a knife stabbed in your back.

**Let's get rid of humans and develop servant creatures**

Step 1: Killing them all

I am Evil Genius and I possess DNA manipulation device, which can create me any animal I would like. Now it is time, to develop a creature which can kill as many people as possible.

But, how should such animal look like?

And: While simple rats or mosquitoes are great killing machines, they do not kill humans directly. They are just helping diseases to spread. I want this to be personal. I want the animal directly attack humans and kill them. And eat them (who has time to hide all the bodies?)

I call you, my evil henchmen. What do you suggest?

**EDIT**
Oops! I forgot one vital info: I am human too. So those creatures should not kill me. Obviously ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, but as this stands I can't see it being anything but an idea-generation question. There are many different types of animals that are fully capable of bringing down a human, especially if you ignore that pesky detail of humans fighting back. (See some of the answers to my old question [How would societal development be impacted if humans were not an apex predator?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/43/29)) How are we going to objectively judge the answers to this? I recommend adding criteria, narrowing this question down and/or focusing it considerably, if you want it to work.

Comment: Oh shoot. And I did start this in Sandbox. Did not wait long enough to get this question sandboxed

Comment: Ok, this question is in Sandbox, again: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/1870/2071